# Access a let/var in another method Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm currently developing with CoreBluetooth and I've managed to get the RSSI-strength. I can print it in the console, but when I want to use it in an IBAction, it wont work. I guess it's because the RSSI var isn't a local variable.

Here is the method where I get the RSSI-strength from:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? String

    let rssi = RSSI // The const that stores the RSSI-data
    print(rssi)

    if device?.contains(BLE_NAME) == true {
        self.manager.stopScan()

        self.peripheral = peripheral
        self.peripheral.delegate = self

        manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
}
```

And here is the IBAction that I want the rssi const to be in:

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    rssiLbl.text = "\(rssi)"
}
```

However, I don't know how to make this work. I bet that this is a really basic question for the most of you, but I just can't make it work.

Comment: Make the `rssi` a class level variable. Once you assign value to it, it will be accessible in your `IBAction`

Comment: @Martin Nordstrom make rssi a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said. Declare rssi as a class-level variable:

```
private var rssi: NSNumber?

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? String

    self.rssi = RSSI
    print(self.rssi)

    if device?.contains(BLE_NAME) == true {
        self.manager.stopScan()

        self.peripheral = peripheral
        self.peripheral.delegate = self

        manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let rssi = self.rssi {
        rssiLbl.text = "\(rssi)"
    } else {
        rssiLbl.text = "Undetermined"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!